# Gerar código (como o option value)

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

Estou a desenvolver um "programa" no visual basic, porem eu gostaria de obter uma informação. Sabem aqueles options values do HTML que selecionamos e ele gera algo? Vou dar o exemplo:
https://jsbin.com/zasodi/edit?html,output / http://pastebin.com/cY87pajT

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer isso no Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta é um tanto vaga mas parece que o que você quer é gerar um DROPDOWNLIST ([Veja um exemplo em W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_value)).

Então, se entendi sua pergunta corretamente, o que você quer é um COMBOBOX e a resposta pode ser encontrada aqui: http://www.macoratti.net/11/01/c_cbo1.htm

Sugiro que leia outros tutoriais neste mesmo site para aprender mais sobre VB.NET.

Espero ter ajudado.